# HTML Code in ASP.NET (Visual Studio) gets Javascript Runtime Error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio

This is part of a `html` code in ASP.NET (Visual Studio) and when I try to run the code, it gives me the following `error`:

> Unhandled exception at line 216, column 63 in http://localhost:55031/WebForm1.aspx
>   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'addInput' is undefined

Some people have been saying that I need to add a `JQuery` script but I keep getting this error. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

This is the HTML code in ASP.NET (Visual Studio):

```
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src=" C:/Users/Desktop/check.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <form method="POST">



    <div id="dynamicInput">

         Please click the Add Another Dimension button to add more dimensions/measurements<br>

    </div>
        <input type="button" value="Add Another Dimension" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">

    </form>



</div>
<div class="button-section">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Checksheet" required />
 <span class="privacy-policy">
 <input type="checkbox" name="field50" required>I agree. 
 </span>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does your javascript file load? I see the `src` attribute links to `C:\...`. I would recommend using a webserver, but if you don't want that, try placing `file://` before your source.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need JQuery to do this.

Comment: Yeah the check.js file was not being referred properly in my code and so I just changed it to src="check.js", and it worked perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the line below:

```
<script src=" C:/Users/Desktop/check.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`C:/Users/Desktop/check.js` is a windows path and not a URL and it won't work correctly. Changing the the `\` to a `/` isn't enough

You need to add the `js` again from a relative or absolute **URL**

Place the `.js` in the same folder with `WebForm1.aspx` then change the above line to:

```
<script src="check.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your path check.js is in the local disk folder, could not be referred.